# Textmate 2 Command Line Support not installing

Tags: textmate2

[image: Preferences -> Terminal]

The TextMate2  (Alpha 9090) terminal support does not install anything in any directory.

Is there any way to grab this script anywhere manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: (Via Michael Sheets)

"Make sure you have the 'Bundle Support' bundle installed in preferences."

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can try. Hold down `shift` when clicking `Check now` to re-install whatever version you have selected (So you can select Normal releases and shift+click to downgrade). I've checked and it works fine for me on 9113. To get the bleeding edge versions `alt` click instead. These modifier keys work together so you can alt+shift+click to re-install the newer version.

These newer versions can contain extra debugging and may not be stable, so YMMV but so far that's not been an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to grab any code, as the "installation" appears simply to change some parameters, rather than to install any new code.  The trick is to click the "install" button anyway ... and then to paste the required line of code (see below) into your .bashrc.

Earlier this evening I was having problems in using TextMate.  I'd installed TextMate earlier in the day ... but the "mate" command in the Terminal was not working (i.e. it did nothing at all). Also, when I typed the code `which mate` into Terminal (to try to find additional information), I received a blank response.

After navigating to TextMate | Preferences | Terminal I saw exactly the message that you are seeing now.  I then followed the instructions shown.

(a) First, I clicked the "Install" button.  Although there was no obvious installation process, something presumably happened.

(b) Second, I copied the line below into my .bashrc file.

```
   export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mate -w"
```

Finally, I closed and reopened Terminal (to reset things) ... and the "mate" command worked!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you may have a permissions issue with /usr/local/bin.  Try opening Terminal and do:

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/mate
touch  /usr/local/bin/mate
ls -al /usr/local/bin/mate
rm     /usr/local/bin/mate
```

See if you get any errors.

With regards to your second question, see this thread on SuperUser: [What is the path to the 'mate' executable in TextMate 2's app bundle?](https://superuser.com/questions/471877/what-is-the-path-to-the-mate-executable-in-textmate-2s-app-bundle/472589).  Once you locate it, you can symlink it:

```
for cmd in mate mate_wait; do
    ln -s /path/to/mate /usr/local/bin/$cmd;
done
```